# Django Xhtml2PDF TypeError

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate and force download a PDF from an HTML file in Django. Here are the steps I took and the codes I did:

views.py:

```
class GeneratePDF(GenericView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('dashboard/generated.html')
        context = {
            "invoice_id": 123,
            "customer_name": "John Cooper",
            "amount": 1399.99,
            "today": "Today",
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
            content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

utils.py:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

The issue here is when I run the view, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /pdf/

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is the full Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/pdf/

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'wkhtmltopdf',
 'easy_pdf']
Installed Middleware:
['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /pdf/
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

All I want to do is to create and download a PDF using a context dictionnary. What is the function that takes 1 argument not two? I tried changing in every line but I always get the same error. Is there something wrong with the function in the utils.py?

I took the code from CodingForEntrepreneurs

Edit: added urls.py

urls.py

```
path('pdf/', views.GeneratePDF, name='pdf'),
```

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`? Have you called `is_view()` in your url path?

Comment: No I did not. I used a simple url call. I will share my urls.py right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For class based views you need to call `<view>.as_view()` when passing to a url path

```
path('pdf/', views.GeneratePDF.as_view(), name='pdf'),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've always used function based views, this is the first time I use CBVs.